# I want to change the color of my container color using CSS. The code I've tried below doesn't seem to work:

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change container color using CSS when i reload it show white color then after proper reload it shows yellow. want yellow color in row instead of white. The code I've tried below doesn't seem to work:

[image]

```css
section#content {
min-height: 400px;
padding-top: 40px;
text-align: left;
background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: first check if wordpress theme has the option to change the background color in customize or use `background : #FFFF00 !important`

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes  that will change all section color is yellow

Comment: Put a bit more context here... Like the HTML code on which this CSS is applied

Answer (score 0):

try to use !important after color code.

Let me know if it solve.

Answer (score 0):

first of all `section#content` ?????

just write `#content` and that's it

and try one of those codes !

```css
#content {
min-height: 400px;
padding-top: 40px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

or

```css
#content {
min-height: 400px;
padding-top: 40px;
text-align: left;
background: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
```

Hope this work.

Comment: that will change all the  row colors in this section

Comment: @MahakMudgal Well then use your code and add `!important` and see what will happen.

Comment: you are right, but it will change color of all rows in this section.

Comment: @MahakMudgal can you please provide the HTML so we can help, or at least tell me what are you doing ! because i dont know what row you are talking about.

Comment: So you want the whole body ?

Comment: No.. i want same row color when site is load

Comment: Tell me more, provide a jsfiddle or codepen so i can check.